# Simulators absent in xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, xcode5, ios-simulator

I have made a project in Xcode and copied the project to another system.  When I opened the project on the other system, there was no option to select a Simulator device (only real Device).  How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Xcode probably hasn't been installed properly on the other system. Try a re-install.

Comment: but its working fine for those project who have made from starting on this system

Comment: did u try by creating new scheme?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode only lets me run for an iOS device (no simulator)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284299/xcode-only-lets-me-run-for-an-ios-device-no-simulator)

Comment: As you have tagged this with Xcode 5, I suggest you upgrade to Xcode 6 as the simulator architecture has changed quite considerably.

Answer (score 5):

Changing deployment target from 4.3 to 6 solved this issue, but if you still have problem go to project -> Build setting and see this if you have selected iOS because on OS X it will not show simulators[image]

Comment: This is correct.  We do not support deployment targets older than 6.0 in the iOS Simulator.  I believe this is mentioned in the Xcode release notes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution (if you haven't found already :)

Under Your project Build Settings

1. **select Deployment section.**
2. **change iOS Deployment Target to a version iOS 5.0 or less.**
3. **now you can go ahead and change the deployment target from device to simulator!**

In my case the deployment target was set to version 5.1 and I still am running snow leopard OS with appropriate JARS copied from xCode 4.3 to make it run with a device running iOS 5.1. However, my simulators do not yet support version 5.1 so till I changed the deployment target to lower version e.g. 5.0 or 4.2 it won't let me run on simulator.